# How to make a TextAreaItem's value clickable and hyperlink in SmartGwt?

Tags: smartgwt

I'm having a dynamic form which is having a TextAreaItem and the value for text Area is populated from database.

I want to make the value of Text Area Clickable and hyperlink ,Could you please help which event handlers and attributes I shuld set to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will want to use a [`LinkItem`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/LinkItem.html) rather than `TextAreaItem`.  A `LinkItem` can be used to show a clickable hyperlink.  You can [set the target](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/LinkItem.html#setTarget%28java.lang.String%29) of the `LinkItem` to "javascript" and add a form item [`ClickHandler`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/events/ClickHandler.html) to perform an action on click.

See the [Forms - Various Controls](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_controls_various) sample.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using LinkItem too but if you make the link editable (`link.setCanEdit(true)`) then you loose the ability of opening the link by clicking on it. Probably because the click handler is now used to edit the field. You might need to add some extra mechanism to open the link, like adding a button or something.

Here it's an example:

```
private void urlForm() {

    url = new LinkItem();
    url.setShowTitle(false);
    url.setCanEdit(true);
    url.setValue("yourURL");

   ButtonItem button = new ButtonItem("Go");
   button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
           Window.open(url.getLinkTitle(), "_blank", "");                       
       }
    });

    urlForm = new DynamicForm();
    urlForm.setNumCols(4);
    urlForm.setFields(url, button);
}
```

Another alternative could be adding a new view to edit the URL value, and leave the LinkItem as non editable, so the link will open when clicking on it.